# Tricky Long Pivot by Reverse Aggregation transformation (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset where I would like to de aggregate the values into their own unique rows as well as perform a pivot, grouping by category.

**Data** updated

```
Period      Date        Area    BB stat AA stat CC stat DD stat BB test AA test CC test DD test BB re   AA re   CC re BB test2  AA test2 CC test2  DD test2                                                
8/1/2016    9/1/2016    NY      5       5       5               1       1       1               0       0       0     0          0       0         0
9/1/2016    10/1/2016   NY      6       6       6               4       4       4               0       0       0     0          0       0         0
8/1/2016    9/1/2016    CA      2       2       2               4       4       4               0       0       0     0          0       0         0
9/1/2016    10/1/2016   CA      1       1       1              -2      -2      -2               0       0       0     0          0       0         0
```

**Desired**

```
Period      Date            Area    stat    test    type    re  test2
8/1/2016    9/1/2016        NY      5       1       BB      0   0
9/1/2016    10/1/2016       NY      6       4       BB      0   0
8/1/2016    9/1/2016        NY      5       1       AA      0   0   
9/1/2016    10/1/2016       NY      6       4       AA      0   0   
8/1/2016    9/1/2016        NY      5       1       CC      0   0
9/1/2016    10/1/2016       NY      6       4       CC      0   0   
8/1/2016    9/1/2016        NY      0       0       DD      0   0
9/1/2016    10/1/2016       NY      0       0       DD      0   0
8/1/2016    9/1/2016        CA      2       4       BB      0   0
9/1/2016    10/1/2016       CA      1       -2      BB      0   0
8/1/2016    9/1/2016        CA      2       4       AA      0   0
9/1/2016    10/1/2016       CA      1       -2      AA      0   0
8/1/2016    9/1/2016        CA      2       4       CC      0   0
9/1/2016    10/1/2016       CA      1       -2      CC      0   0
8/1/2016    9/1/2016        CA      0       0       DD      0   0
9/1/2016    10/1/2016       CA      0       0       DD      0   0
```

**Doing**

```
value_vars = ["BB stat",    "AA stat",  "CC stat",  "DD stat",  "BB test",
"AA test",  "CC test",  "DD test",  "BB re",    "AA re",    "CC re"]
df = df.melt(id_vars=["Period", "Date", "Area"], value_vars=value_vars)


temp_df = df.variable.str.split("_", 1, expand=True)
df["type"] = temp_df[0]
df["name"] = temp_df[1]
df = df.drop(columns=["variable"])
first_half = df.iloc[:len(df)//2]
second_half = df.iloc[len(df)//2:]
df = pd.merge(first_half, second_half, on=["Period", "Date", "Area", "type"], suffixes=("_1", "_2"))


df.rename(columns = {'value_3':'stat''value_2':'test', 'value_1':'re'}, inplace = True)
df.drop(columns=["name_1", "name_2"], inplace=True)
df = df[[ "Period",     "Date",         "Area", "stat", "test", "type", "re"    ]]



df.sort_values(["Area", "type"], ascending=False, inplace=True)
df.to_markdown()
```

The following code fails to capture all the output columns. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html):

```
pd.wide_to_long(df, 
                stubnames=['AA', 'BB','CC','DD'],
                i=['Period','Date','Area'],
                j='',
                sep=' ',
                suffix='(test|re|stat)'
).unstack(level=-1, fill_value=0).stack(level=0).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
      Period       Date Area type   re  stat  test
0   8/1/2016   9/1/2016   CA   AA  0.0   2.0   4.0
1   8/1/2016   9/1/2016   CA   BB  0.0   2.0   4.0
2   8/1/2016   9/1/2016   CA   CC  0.0   2.0   4.0
3   8/1/2016   9/1/2016   CA   DD  NaN   0.0   0.0
4   8/1/2016   9/1/2016   NY   AA  0.0   5.0   1.0
5   8/1/2016   9/1/2016   NY   BB  0.0   5.0   1.0
6   8/1/2016   9/1/2016   NY   CC  0.0   5.0   1.0
7   8/1/2016   9/1/2016   NY   DD  NaN   0.0   0.0
8   9/1/2016  10/1/2016   CA   AA  0.0   1.0  -2.0
9   9/1/2016  10/1/2016   CA   BB  0.0   1.0  -2.0
10  9/1/2016  10/1/2016   CA   CC  0.0   1.0  -2.0
11  9/1/2016  10/1/2016   CA   DD  NaN   0.0   0.0
12  9/1/2016  10/1/2016   NY   AA  0.0   6.0   4.0
13  9/1/2016  10/1/2016   NY   BB  0.0   6.0   4.0
14  9/1/2016  10/1/2016   NY   CC  0.0   6.0   4.0
15  9/1/2016  10/1/2016   NY   DD  NaN   0.0   0.0
```

Comment: Hi thank you - for some reason the 'DD' output isn't showing. Any suggestion?

Comment: because your data doesn't have a `DD re` column. You can chain that with a `fillna(0)`.

Comment: thank you - I think this works in all cases - will try and update solution @Quang Hoang

Answer (score 2):

Well asked question.

I think what we need to do is use [a pivot table](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html)

```
import pandas as pd

# OP data
data = {'Period': ['8/1/2016', '9/1/2016', '8/1/2016', '9/1/2016'],
        'Date': ['9/1/2016', '10/1/2016', '9/1/2016', '10/1/2016'],
        'Area': ['NY', 'NY', 'CA', 'CA'],
        'BB stat': [5, 6, 2, 1],
        'AA stat': [5, 6, 2, 1],
        'CC stat': [5, 6, 2, 1],
        'DD stat': [0, 0, 0, 0],
        'BB test': [1, 4, 4, -2],
        'AA test': [1, 4, 4, -2],
        'CC test': [1, 4, 4, -2],
        'DD test': [0, 0, 0, 0],
        'BB re': [0, 0, 0, 0],
        'AA re': [0, 0, 0, 0],
        'CC re': [0, 0, 0, 0]}

# Convert the dictionary to a DataFrame and process it
df = pd.DataFrame(data) \
    .melt(id_vars=["Period", "Date", "Area"]) \
    .assign(**pd.DataFrame(df.melt(id_vars=["Period", "Date", "Area"])['variable'].str.extract(r'([A-Z]{2})\s([a-z]{2,4})', expand=True).values, columns=['type', 'category'])) \
    .drop(columns=['variable']) \
    .pivot_table(index=["Period", "Date", "Area", "type"], columns="category", values="value").reset_index() \
    .reindex(columns=['Period', 'Date', 'Area', 'stat', 'test', 'type', 're']) \
    .sort_values(['Area', 'type'], ascending=False)
```

Comment: Thank you much. Nicely condensed. I will try to see if I obtain the desired output. @artemis

Comment: Hi @artemis - console is saying: NameError: name 'melted_df' is not defined - I will research this

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo on my part. Code is correctd @Lynn

Answer (score 2):

One option is with [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) - in this case we use the special placeholder `.value` to identify the parts of the column that we want to remain as headers, while the rest get collated into a new column :

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

(df
.pivot_longer(
    index = ['Period', 'Date', 'Area'], 
    names_to = ('type', '.value'), 
    names_sep = " ",
    sort_by_appearance=True)
.fillna({"re":0}, downcast='infer')
) 
      Period       Date Area type  stat  test  re  test2
0   8/1/2016   9/1/2016   NY   BB     5     1   0      0
1   8/1/2016   9/1/2016   NY   AA     5     1   0      0
2   8/1/2016   9/1/2016   NY   CC     5     1   0      0
3   8/1/2016   9/1/2016   NY   DD     0     0   0      0
4   9/1/2016  10/1/2016   NY   BB     6     4   0      0
5   9/1/2016  10/1/2016   NY   AA     6     4   0      0
6   9/1/2016  10/1/2016   NY   CC     6     4   0      0
7   9/1/2016  10/1/2016   NY   DD     0     0   0      0
8   8/1/2016   9/1/2016   CA   BB     2     4   0      0
9   8/1/2016   9/1/2016   CA   AA     2     4   0      0
10  8/1/2016   9/1/2016   CA   CC     2     4   0      0
11  8/1/2016   9/1/2016   CA   DD     0     0   0      0
12  9/1/2016  10/1/2016   CA   BB     1    -2   0      0
13  9/1/2016  10/1/2016   CA   AA     1    -2   0      0
14  9/1/2016  10/1/2016   CA   CC     1    -2   0      0
15  9/1/2016  10/1/2016   CA   DD     0     0   0      0
```

Another option, with `pd.stack`:

```py
index = ['Period', 'Date', 'Area']
temp = df.set_index(index)
# default separator is white space
temp.columns = temp.columns.str.split(expand = True)
temp.columns.names = ['type', None]
(temp
.stack("type")
.fillna({"re":0}, downcast='infer')
.reset_index()
)

      Period       Date Area type  re  stat  test  test2
0   8/1/2016   9/1/2016   NY   AA   0     5     1      0
1   8/1/2016   9/1/2016   NY   BB   0     5     1      0
2   8/1/2016   9/1/2016   NY   CC   0     5     1      0
3   8/1/2016   9/1/2016   NY   DD   0     0     0      0
4   9/1/2016  10/1/2016   NY   AA   0     6     4      0
5   9/1/2016  10/1/2016   NY   BB   0     6     4      0
6   9/1/2016  10/1/2016   NY   CC   0     6     4      0
7   9/1/2016  10/1/2016   NY   DD   0     0     0      0
8   8/1/2016   9/1/2016   CA   AA   0     2     4      0
9   8/1/2016   9/1/2016   CA   BB   0     2     4      0
10  8/1/2016   9/1/2016   CA   CC   0     2     4      0
11  8/1/2016   9/1/2016   CA   DD   0     0     0      0
12  9/1/2016  10/1/2016   CA   AA   0     1    -2      0
13  9/1/2016  10/1/2016   CA   BB   0     1    -2      0
14  9/1/2016  10/1/2016   CA   CC   0     1    -2      0
15  9/1/2016  10/1/2016   CA   DD   0     0     0      0
```

Comment: Hi thank you @sammywemmy - it is giving this error:
   .fillna({"re":0}, downcast='infer')
                                       ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Is there a need for a closed () or lack there of?

Comment: did you close the bracket? have a look at the parentheses, it is possible that there is a missing one

Comment: Hi @sammywemmy I have another set of 4 columns ('AA test2', 'BB test2', 'CC test2', 'DD test2') I updated** in my original dataset, how can I account for these using the script you have provided?) The error I get is : ValueError: The length of names_to does not match the number of levels extracted. The length of names_to is 2 while the number of levels extracted is 4. trying to tweak this - any suggestion please?

Comment: There is no `AA test2` in your data

Comment: My apologies I just updated - wondering how to incorporate if I have 4 additional columns or more @sammywemmy

Comment: it should work as long as it is the same white space for each column

Comment: I have updated the outputs based on your updated data. Note that I did not change the code. As long as the pattern is consistent, either the `pivot_longer` solution or the `pd.stack` solution works

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
cols = ['Period', 'Date', 'Area']
out = df.melt(cols)
out = (pd.concat([out, 
                  out['variable'].str.split(' ', expand=True)
                  .set_axis(['type', 'aux'], axis=1)], axis=1)
       .drop(['variable'], axis=1))
(out.pivot(index = cols + ['type'], columns='aux').droplevel(0, axis=1)
 .reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1).fillna(0))
```

Output:

```
      Period       Date Area type   re  stat  test
0   8/1/2016   9/1/2016   CA   AA  0.0   2.0   4.0
1   8/1/2016   9/1/2016   CA   BB  0.0   2.0   4.0
2   8/1/2016   9/1/2016   CA   CC  0.0   2.0   4.0
3   8/1/2016   9/1/2016   CA   DD  0.0   0.0   0.0
4   8/1/2016   9/1/2016   NY   AA  0.0   5.0   1.0
5   8/1/2016   9/1/2016   NY   BB  0.0   5.0   1.0
6   8/1/2016   9/1/2016   NY   CC  0.0   5.0   1.0
7   8/1/2016   9/1/2016   NY   DD  0.0   0.0   0.0
8   9/1/2016  10/1/2016   CA   AA  0.0   1.0  -2.0
9   9/1/2016  10/1/2016   CA   BB  0.0   1.0  -2.0
10  9/1/2016  10/1/2016   CA   CC  0.0   1.0  -2.0
11  9/1/2016  10/1/2016   CA   DD  0.0   0.0   0.0
12  9/1/2016  10/1/2016   NY   AA  0.0   6.0   4.0
13  9/1/2016  10/1/2016   NY   BB  0.0   6.0   4.0
14  9/1/2016  10/1/2016   NY   CC  0.0   6.0   4.0
15  9/1/2016  10/1/2016   NY   DD  0.0   0.0   0.0
```